# Create a CSV from a Vector in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have this

```
(defstruct book :title :year)
(def e [
        (struct book "John" 123)
        (struct book "Ashwani" 456)
        ])
```

I want to create a CSV file which has 2 rows from this Vector

```
John,123
Ashwani,456
```

I can produce this result on console by using doseq

```
(doseq [x e]
  ( println (x :title) ","  (x :year)  ))
```

I am trying to use `clojure.contrib.duck-streams/spit` to create this CSV but I am not able to iterate thought and create a string and pass it to spit.

What is the best way to achieve this . I was hoping to come up with some reduce function and then pass it to spit and create this csv. (In C# I would open a stream and write each line and in the end close the stream and save the file and my brain is making me think in the foreach way but I am sure there must be some functional way to achieve this)

Comment: CSV isn't so simple as you think, for example, you need to quote string if it contains comma inside. It's better to look to some of clojure csv reader/writers, for example, https://github.com/jonase/cljcsv

Comment: @Allex Ott - Thanks for that. In my scenario it does not but still the link you gave is very helpful for my final solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with a reduce and duck-streams/spit.

But probably better to use duck-streams/write-lines.  That way you don't have to worry about using the proper O/S dependent line separator.

```
(use 'clojure.contrib.duck-streams)

(write-lines f
  (map #(str (% :title) ","  (% :year)) e))
```